SmartGWT reduced environment migration from JDK1.8 to JDK 17.0
SmartGWT Version 13.0-p20240525
Java version 17.0.11
Servlet api version 5.0.0.0
GlassFish6 application server
Version Jetty 9.4.31.v20200723

We are currently trying to migrate the reduced SmartGWT environment from Java 1.8.0_245 to 17.0.11, we have a class that implements ServletContextListener, the application deploys and displays correctly the data locally using Jetty, however, when we publish it in the GlassFish6 application server we get the following error:
An error has occurred Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener. Please see server.log for more details. An error has occurred Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener. Please see server.log for more details.

Attached are the pom.xml files with the dependencies used and the web.xml file:
Principal pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.focuss</groupId>
    <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <gwt.version>2.8.2</gwt.version>
        <smartgwt.version>13.0-p20240525</smartgwt.version>
        <servlets.version>5.0.0</servlets.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <skipModule>true</skipModule>
                    <launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir</launcherDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.isomorphic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>isc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.5</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.isomorphic.extras</groupId>
                            <artifactId>isomorphic-m2pluginextras</artifactId>
                           <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
                        </dependency>       
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>17</source>
                        <target>17</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <skipModule>true</skipModule>                        
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>BuiltInDsMvn-client</module>
        <module>BuiltInDsMvn-server</module>
    </modules>

</project>

Server pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.focuss</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlets.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use SQLDataSources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.pro</groupId>
        <artifactId>isomorphic-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add support for the sample database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.pro</groupId>
        <artifactId>isomorphic-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.isomorphic</groupId>
          <artifactId>isc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <smartclientRuntimeDir>${project.parent.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir/builtindsmvn/sc</smartclientRuntimeDir>
            <dataSourcesDir>WEB-INF/ds/classic-models</dataSourcesDir>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn-client</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <type>war</type>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
              <configuration>
                <webApp>
                  <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
                    <resourcesAsCSV>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp,${project.parent.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir/</resourcesAsCSV>
                  </baseResource>
                  <jettyEnvXml>${project.basedir}/src/etc/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                </webApp>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>

Client pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
    <parent>
    <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.focuss</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <artifactId>BuiltInDsMvn-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>gwt-app</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Standard GWT depdendency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The SmartGWT core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.pro</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt-pro</artifactId>
            <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <moduleName>com.focuss.builtindsmvn.BuiltInDsMvn</moduleName>
                    <moduleShortName>builtindsmvn</moduleShortName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 

    <listener>
         <listener-class>com.isomorphic.base.InitListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IDACall</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.IDACall</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IDACall</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/builtindsmvn/sc/IDACall/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DataSourceLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DataSourceLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/builtindsmvn/sc/DataSourceLoader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProjectLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.ProjectLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProjectLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/builtindsmvn/sc/projectLoader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScreenLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.ScreenLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ScreenLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/builtindsmvn/sc/screenLoader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/samples</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>

Deploy the reduced smartGWT environment with java 17.0 on the GlassFish6 application server.
